# How to run just a few testcases of a testsuite via commandline?

Tags: squish

I want to make a command line call of `squishrunner.exe --testsuite` with just about 200 of my 400 testcases. I think, it's not the right way to make a looooooong command line call with all 200 `--testcase oneOfMyManyManyTestcases` options. How should I solve this?

---

In the GUI (Squish 6.1), I can set all testcase checkboxes on I want, and this way define a subset which runs on pressing the testsuite play-button. But when closing the GUI with half the checkboxes on, and starting the test from command line, squishrunner executes the whole testsuite and does not care about the checkboxes, but I don't want that.

Comment: I read about BDD scenarios but I think it's the wrong way, because it seems it's for copying parts of testcases to new testcases, means a few steps of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squish 6.2 will definitely solve your issue, as it has "tagging" feature introduced with it. 
https://www.froglogic.com/news/release-squish-gui-tester-6-2-with-remote-file-system-access/

Answer (score 1):

There are some benefits to splitting up the execution...

You might write a shell script that separately invokes each test case, checks for pass/fail, gathers appropriate logs, etc.

We independently execute each of our 500+ test cases and process results for each execution independently.

If you want to execute 200 of them together, just write a script that iterates over your list.

If you don't have 6.2, you can write your meta file to organize tests in groups and execute groups with a script as well.

If you do have 6.2, it seems the tags should help.